# Prove or disprove: if $T$ is rv and $X$ is coordinatewise measurable, then $X\big(T(\omega),\omega\big)$ is rv

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

> Let $\Omega$ ne a non-empty set and $\mathcal{F}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\Omega$. Let also  $T:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is a random variable (rv) and $X:\mathbb{R}\times \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is such that:
>
> for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$ function $X(t,\cdot):\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is random variable and
>
> for all $\omega\in \Omega$ function $X(\cdot,\omega):\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.
>
> Prove or disprove: $\omega \overset{g}{\mapsto} X\big(T(\omega),\omega\big)$
> is a random variable.

**Attempt.** I believe the answer is yes. Let $B$ be a Borel set of $\mathbb{R}$, so:

\begin{eqnarray}g^{-1}(B)&=&\{\omega \in \Omega:g(\omega)\in B\}\nonumber\\
&=&\{\omega \in \Omega: T(\omega)=t\in \mathbb{R},~X(t,\omega)\in B\}\nonumber\\
&=&\bigcup_{t\in \mathbb{R}}T^{-1}(\{t\})\cap X(t,\cdot)^{-1}(B).\nonumber
\end{eqnarray}
Since $T$ and $X(t,\cdot)$ are  random variables, sets $T^{-1}(\{t\})$ and   $X(t,\cdot)^{-1}(B)$  belong in $\mathcal{F}$. However, $\mathcal{F}$ being a $\sigma$-algebra, is closed under countable operations on sets. How can we turn $\bigcup_{t\in \mathbb{R}}$ to a countable union in order to guarantee that $g^{-1}(B)$ belongs in $\mathcal{F}$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: $X(\cdot,\omega)\,:\,\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous (you have not used that so far).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X(T(\omega),\omega)=\lim X([nT(\omega)]/n,\omega)$ where $[x]$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$. It is easy to see that $X([nT(\omega)]/n,\omega)$ is measurable by considering the events $\{\omega: k \leq T(\omega) <k+\frac 1 n\}$.

Comment: Thank you. How exactly do we prove that $\omega \mapsto X(\frac{[nT(\omega)]}{n},\omega)$ is a random variable?

Comment: You can write it as $\sum_k X(\frac k n, \omega) I_{\{\omega: \frac k n \leq T(\omega) <\frac k n+\frac 1 n\}}$. Each term is measurable so the sum is measurable.

Answer (score 1):

Approximate $T$ with a sequence of simple functions $T_n\to T$. Then, by continuity of $t\mapsto X(t,\cdot)$, $X_{T_n}\to X_T$ and each $X_{T_n}$ is measurable (here $X_{T}(\omega)=X(T(\omega),\omega)$).

Comment: Thank you. Why $T_n'$s being simple guarantee that  $X_{T_n}$ is a random variable?

Comment: $T_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k 1_{A_k}$, where $\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k=\Omega$ and $T_n$ is constant on each $A_k$. Thus, $X_{T_n}$ is measurable on each $A_k$.